# When using JDBC with Oracle DB how to find if the connection really timed out or if credentials were wrong?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I already have the connection string and DBA username. I accept DBA password from the user.
To check if the password provided by him is correct, I try to create a connection using

```
    String connString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + connDesc;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("user", user);
    props.put("password", pwd);

    props.put("internal_logon", "sysdba");
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, props);
```

Now when it throws SQLException I need to find if that exception is because of wrong password or network timeout. Is there any way to do that?
Also, is there any better way to validate password than what I'm currently doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SQLException.getErrorCode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode%28%29) method to read the Oracle-specific error code for the error.

For an invalid username/password combination, the error code is 1017.

It's not clear to me exactly what error you mean by 'network timeout'.  If the message is `The Network Adapter could not establish the connection`, then the error code you want appears to be 17002.  (I got this error attempting to connect to my local Oracle XE instance using JDBC but with the TNS listener shut down.)

There isn't a better way of validating a username/password than attempting to create a connection to the database using that username and password.